# What is conditional assembly branch instruction duration for different situations in ARM Cortex-M4?

Tags: assembly, arm, timing, cortex-m

I'm trying to determine the exact duration in clock cycles for the simple delay loop below :

```
loop:  subs        r2, r2, 1 
       bne         loop
```

The [Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0439/b/Programmers-Model/Instruction-set-summary/Cortex-M4-instructions) says : 1 + P, where P is:

> The number of cycles required for a pipeline refill. This ranges from 1 to 3 depending on the alignment and width of the target instruction, and whether the processor manages to speculate the address early.

ARM9 (5-stage pipeline) has 3 cycles in this case for `bne` and 1 cycle for `subs`. Cortex-M4 has a 3-stage pipeline, but it seems quite similar since the first two stages are the same...

So my question is: according to the reference manual it can be from 2 to 4 cycles, right? When is it 2, when 3 and when 4? In a 3-stage pipeline, it would be logical to have at least 3, but it seems possible to have only 2 cycles. Is there some kind of branch prediction involved?

Comment: This is not deterministic.  It can be repeatable, but if you change the alignment of the code and other factors the same loop, same machine code, will take a different number of system clocks to execute.  some implementations have a cache between the flash and cpu that you cannot turn off.

Answer (score 4):

The Cortex-M4 does not have branch prediction (at least not in the sense that it will start executing a branch before it is actually taken). It does however incorporate a Prefetch Unit (PFU), which fetches the next (consecutive) instructions from memory in its FIFO, so they can be directly accessed by the execution unit.
It also speculatively prefetches instructions from branch target addresses. This means that if a (conditional) branch target is known in the second pipeline stage, that memory address will be prefetched.

The Cortex-M4 Technical Reference Manual indeed says the the number of clock cycles for the branch instruction is `1 + P`, where `P` is the number of cycles required for a pipeline refill.
It also contains a footnote saying:

> Conditional branch completes in a single cycle if the branch is not taken.

So, what this means, is that the execution of the branch instruction itself (i.e., checking if the condition is true or false) takes only one clock cycle. If the condition is false and thus the branch is not taken, the execution unit can directly continue executing the next instruction, which was already prefetched by the PFU.

However, if the condition was true and the branch is taken, part of the pipeline must be flushed and reloaded. I can't exactly tell when this will take 1 cycle or when it will take 3 cycles, but if the target instruction is a 32-bit instruction on a 16-bit aligned address, it might take an additional memory read, since the memory bus is 32-bit (hence the "*depending on the alignment and width of the target instruction*").

I'm not completely sure about the "*and whether the processor manages to speculate the address early*" part. I guess this is because the `P` in the documentation is also used for instructions such as `MOV PC, Rm`, where there might be a data dependency because the instruction does not have a fixed offset (the value of `Rm` is not yet known at time of decoding).